# What's actually meaning of SQLite cache status output by dumpsys

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm really confused the below output which was generated by dumpsys:

**DATABASES**

```
  pgsz     dbsz   Lookaside(b)          cache  Dbname

     1     3176            117   7663/1635/21  webviewCache.db

                                    2822/16/5  (pooled # 1) webviewCache.db
```

Why list three items in the cache column and what are their meanings?

That's appreciate to get your comments.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's clear now, though it is too late. I checked source codes and got the below lines in SQLiteDebug.java:

/** statement cache stats: hits/misses/cachesize */

public String cache;

Anyway, thanks for your kindly attentions.